# Why does Google's Geolocation API think that localhost is in Iraq?

Tags: ruby, google-geocoding-api, geokit

Using the [geokit](https://github.com/geokit/geokit) gem in irb:

```
>> Geokit::Geocoders::secure = false
=> false
>> Geokit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.geocode("::1").full_address
=> "1, Madain, Iraq"
```

What the...?

Answer (score 0):

You are geocoding "::1" as an address, which is extremely ambiguous and due to yield anything.

The [Geokit](https://github.com/geokit/geokit/blob/master/lib/geokit/geocoders/google.rb) gem uses the **Geocoding** API, which resolves **postal** addresses into latlng coordinates. This is the API you are actually using:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

If you want to find coordinates for **IP** addresses, you need something that talks to a **Geolocation** API, such a Google's. This is what you need:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro

The only IP address this API will let you geolocation is your own, and that means the public IP you'll see when visiting http://whatismyip.com